# How to make a digital magazine responsive in Barisco?

Tags: barisco

I'm building a digital magazine in [Barisco](http://barisco.com/). At first I didn't encounter any issues. On my iPad everything looks fine expect the height. But on PCs I have problems with the width and the height. It doesn't seem to be responsive.

On the Barisco website it says you can do responsive design. And I've seen several examples that are definitely responsive like this one: http://sustainableliving.unilever.nl/

How do I enable responsiveness?

Here's the link to my test magazine: http://wildlifexchange.barisco.com/

Comment: it's offtopic for [webapps.se]. As our [help page](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) mentions, desing/dev. of web apps is offtopic.

Comment: Barisco is not a programming tool and I'm not building an application. Barisco is a web application. And I'm asking a question on how to use it. So I think it is not off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to make a responsive design in Barisco. I think you are confused with fluid design. Fluid design means that everything scales to the right proportion when the screen is smaller like on a phone or bigger like on a desktop.
Responsive means that you have to make a different designs for different screen formats and that is (still) not possible unfortunately.